# why do object particles get created offset from the mesh I have selected for the particles to be on top of?

Tags: particles, weight-painting

I am trying to create a donut with sprinkles, so I selected the icing, selected hair as the particle system and then changed it from path to object and chose the object sphere (or the sprinkle).

the sprinkles get added like in the picture below automatically

[image: picture demonstrating particle dilemma]

I tried weight painting the icicng thinking it would shift the  particles but it didn't
[image: Weight paint image]

Comment: You likely moved your particle object away from the origin in edit mode. Select your particle object and move it around in different directions in edit mode - you'll see what it does to the particle offset..

Comment: perfect that solved it. thank you very much